# hasattr for nested attributes

Tags: python

I need something like this (pseudocode):

```
if hasattr(object, 'detail.infotext')
```

I mean I want to check if object has attribute `details` and if it has, then if `details` has a attribute named `infotext`

I could do it like this:

```
if hasattr(object, 'detail'):
    if hasattr(object.detail, 'infotext'):
        do something
```

But one-liners are so much easier to read.

Comment: `if hasattr(object, 'detail') and hasattr(object.detail, 'infotext'):`? Lazy evaluation means the second `hasattr` only gets called if the first is `True`.

Answer (score 6):

I know this isn't really what you want to do, but it's more pythonic anyway (if you know the names of the attributes you're looking for explicitly):

```
try:
   do something with object.detail.infotext
except AttributeError:
   do something else
```

Comment: AKA [EAFP: Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAFP#Exceptions).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to actually use your attribute values, `operator.attrgetter` (in Python 2.6+) might also be useful. You still need to catch an exception, apart from that it's quite straightforward:

```
from operator import attrgetter

try:
   print attrgetter("detail.infotext")(object)
except:
   <handle exception>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but it should work:

```
def hasattrpath(obj, path):
    parts = path.split(".")
    for part in parts:
        if hasattr(obj, part):
            obj = getattr(obj, part)
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return True
```

But unless you have such kind of tests everywhere in your code base with deeply nested path expressions, jonrsharpe's comment is probably the most straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0):

I used to something like in my project;

```
attr = 'detail.infotext'.split('.')
if len(attr) == 1:
    return getattr(item, attr[0], "")
else:
    return getattr(getattr(item, attr[0], ""), attr[1], "")
```

or, just one liner statement;

```
    attr = "detail.infotext"
    if hasattr(item, attr.rsplit('.', 1)[0]) and hasattr(getattr(item, attr.rsplit('.', 1)[0]), attr.rsplit('.', 1)[1]):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but here is another approach building off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54547158/10682164) answer which had a nice solution for nested `getattr`...

```py
import functools

def rhasattr(obj, path):
    try:
        functools.reduce(getattr, path.split("."), obj)
        return True
    except AttributeError:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and wasn't happy with the above answers because they don't go to infinite depth. I created this helper function which I tend to use for this problem. There's probably places where it doesn't work or break, but so far so good.

```
import copy
def check_if_obj_contains_nested_attribute_path(obj, nested_attr):
    '''Determine if object has the provided nested path - returns True of False
    
    :param str nested_attr: the nested attribute path e.g. 'status.load_balancer.ingress'
    :param obj: The object that you want to test for the attribute on
    '''
    # divide attribute path string into dot parts
    parts = nested_attr.split('.')
    temp_obj = copy.deepcopy(obj)
    
    for part in parts:
        if hasattr(temp_obj, part):
            temp_obj = getattr(temp_obj, part)
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

So now I can just use it like:

```
result_bool = check_if_obj_contains_nested_attribute_path(obj, 'status.load_balancer.ingress')
```

I'm sure there's someone around who can probably improve this with unexpected type captures and more efficient code in less lines etc... but it does the job for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

- The best way to get child-th value from an object:

```
from operator import attrgetter

def get_nested_val(main_obj, fields_str):
    result = None
    try:
        result = attrgetter(fields_str)(main_obj)
    except Exception as ex:
        pass
    finally:
        return result
```

Usage:

```
product = Product.objects.filter(id=101)[0]
get_nested_val(product, 'customer.document.email')
Out[1]: 'jack@gmail.com'
```