# getattr and setattr on nested subobjects / chained properties?

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, attributes, setattr

I have an object (`Person`) that has multiple subobjects (`Pet, Residence`) as properties. I want to be able to dynamically set the properties of these subobjects like so:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pet = Pet()
        self.residence = Residence()

class Pet(object):
    def __init__(self,name='Fido',species='Dog'):
        self.name = name
        self.species = species

class Residence(object):
    def __init__(self,type='House',sqft=None):
        self.type = type
        self.sqft=sqft


if __name__=='__main__':
    p=Person()
    setattr(p,'pet.name','Sparky')
    setattr(p,'residence.type','Apartment')
    print p.__dict__
```

Currently I get the wrong output: `{'pet': <__main__.Pet object at 0x10c5ec050>, 'residence': <__main__.Residence object at 0x10c5ec0d0>, 'pet.name': 'Sparky', 'residence.type': 'Apartment'}`

As you can see, instead of setting the `name` attribute on the `Pet` subobject of the `Person`, a new attribute `pet.name` is created on the `Person`.

- I cannot specify `person.pet` to `setattr()` because different sub-objects will be set by the same method, which parses some text and fills in the object attributes if/when a relevant key is found.
- Is there a easy/builtin way to accomplish this?
- Or perhaps I need to write a recursive function to parse the string and call `getattr()` multiple times until the necessary subobject is found and then call `setattr()` on that found subobject?

Comment: similar for `dict`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14692747

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You could use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
import functools

def rsetattr(obj, attr, val):
    pre, _, post = attr.rpartition('.')
    return setattr(rgetattr(obj, pre) if pre else obj, post, val)

# using wonder's beautiful simplification: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31174295/getattr-and-setattr-on-nested-objects/31174427?noredirect=1#comment86638618_31174427

def rgetattr(obj, attr, *args):
    def _getattr(obj, attr):
        return getattr(obj, attr, *args)
    return functools.reduce(_getattr, [obj] + attr.split('.'))
```

`rgetattr` and `rsetattr` are drop-in replacements for `getattr` and `setattr`,
which can also handle dotted `attr` strings.

---

```
import functools

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pet = Pet()
        self.residence = Residence()

class Pet(object):
    def __init__(self,name='Fido',species='Dog'):
        self.name = name
        self.species = species

class Residence(object):
    def __init__(self,type='House',sqft=None):
        self.type = type
        self.sqft=sqft

def rsetattr(obj, attr, val):
    pre, _, post = attr.rpartition('.')
    return setattr(rgetattr(obj, pre) if pre else obj, post, val)

def rgetattr(obj, attr, *args):
    def _getattr(obj, attr):
        return getattr(obj, attr, *args)
    return functools.reduce(_getattr, [obj] + attr.split('.'))
```

---

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    p = Person()
    print(rgetattr(p, 'pet.favorite.color', 'calico'))
    # 'calico'

    try:
        # Without a default argument, `rgetattr`, like `getattr`, raises
        # AttributeError when the dotted attribute is missing
        print(rgetattr(p, 'pet.favorite.color'))
    except AttributeError as err:
        print(err)
        # 'Pet' object has no attribute 'favorite'

    rsetattr(p, 'pet.name', 'Sparky')
    rsetattr(p, 'residence.type', 'Apartment')
    print(p.__dict__)
    print(p.pet.name)
    # Sparky
    print(p.residence.type)
    # Apartment
```

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to do a `rgetattr` that also supports the `default` parameter?

Comment: @RedX: The post has been updated to include a `default` parameter. I wish I could make it a little simpler, but c'est la vie.

Comment: Will this handle array indexed attributes too? e.g. "pets[0].favorite.color"

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your inspiration, But I've made a simplified implementation with the same effect: https://gist.github.com/wonderbeyond/d293e7a2af1de4873f2d757edd580288

Comment: you can add `AttributeError` handling there

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of having *args be a variable argument? Getattr documentation only appears to accept a single value.

Comment: Is there a reason to use functools.reduce() instead of an recursive function?

Comment: @shouldsee: Python has a [maximum recursion depth](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3323001/190597). In Python, [iteration is generally faster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2651112/190597) than an equivalent recursive solution.

Comment: @unutbu, I see. It's probably me too used to writing and reading recursive functions since they are generally more intuitive than looping.

Comment: In case anyone is looking for nested `hasattr` as well, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65781864/10682164) is an approach based on the excellent answers to this question.

Comment: This can further be extended for `rhasattr`. [Check here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67303315/5681083)

Comment: note:
If you want type safety compliance and mypy not to complain you can use :
`functools.reduce(lambda obj, obj2: getattr(obj, str(obj2)), "pet.names".split('.'), initial_obj)`

Comment: Using `operator.attrgetter` would work for `rgetattr` - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65355793/281545. Would be great to have a library solution for setting nested attributes  (provided intermediate objects exist or are created via a __getattr__ override)

Answer (score 80):

For an out of the box solution, you can use [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter):

```
from operator import attrgetter
attrgetter(dotted_path)(obj)
```

Comment: I guess I was looking for a corresponding `attrsetter` so I could both get and set - is there a way to do that with this approach?

Comment: Note that `attrgetter` doesn't support a default argument like `getattr` does. See [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue14384).

Comment: @JTrana you can use `attrgetter` to get the parent object and then use setattr on it

Comment: @Plagon Can you explain please what you meant?

Comment: @demberto imagine that we want to set the name of the pet's name in a person object. We can get the name as follows ``attrgetter('pet.name')(p)``.  To change the name we get the parent pet object ``pet = attrgetter('pet')(p)`` and then change the name ``setattr(pet, 'name', 'Arnold')``. While it is trivial for this example, it works for any number of hierarchies.

Comment: Yep that is the correct solution for getting the attribute - but is there an _out of the box solution_ for setting the dotted attribute? (provided intermediate objects exist or are created via a `__getattr__` override)

Answer (score 9):

For one parent and one child:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    p = Person()

    parent, child = 'pet.name'.split('.')
    setattr(getattr(p, parent), child, 'Sparky')

    parent, child = 'residence.type'.split('.')
    setattr(getattr(p, parent), child, 'Sparky')

    print p.__dict__
```

This is simpler than the other answers for this particular use case.

Answer (score 8):

unutbu's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31174427/2683842) has a "bug". After `getattr()` fails and is replaced by `default`, it continues calling `getattr` on `default`.

Example: `rgetattr(object(), "nothing.imag", 1)` should equal `1` in my opinion, but it returns `0`:

- `getattr(object(), 'nothing', 1)`  == 1.
- `getattr(1, 'imag', 1)`  == 0 (since 1 is real and has no complex component).

### Solution

I modified rgetattr to return `default` at the first missing attribute:

```
import functools

DELIMITER = "."

def rgetattr(obj, path: str, *default):
    """
    :param obj: Object
    :param path: 'attr1.attr2.etc'
    :param default: Optional default value, at any point in the path
    :return: obj.attr1.attr2.etc
    """

    attrs = path.split(DELIMITER)
    try:
        return functools.reduce(getattr, attrs, obj)
    except AttributeError:
        if default:
            return default[0]
        raise
```

Comment: Can you explain why *default is a positional argument when only its first element is ever accessed?

Comment: Ah I understand now. For anyone else: it is just a way to easily decide if a default value was given. The tuple `*default` will be empty if no default was set, therefore an `if default` will return `False`. If `default` has an element then we can return it as the default value. Usually this is solved by initializing an object and naming it `_DEFAULT` or something similar and having the kwarg `default=_DEFAULT`, but this solution is much simpler, if a bit non-obvious to someone that hasn't seen it before.

Comment: it was absolutely non-obvious to me either, but I kinda borrowed it from the other answer (but named it default instead).

Answer (score 4):

And a easy to understand three-liner based on jimbo1qaz's answer, reduced to the very limit:

```
def rgetattr(obj, path, default):
    try:
        return functools.reduce(getattr, path.split(), obj)
    except AttributeError:
        return default
```

Usage:

```
>>> class O(object):
...     pass
... o = O()
... o.first = O()
... o.first.second = O()
... o.first.second.third = 42
... rgetattr(o, 'first second third', None)
42
```

Just keep in mind that "space" is not a typical delimiter for this use case.

Answer (score 4):

This should be a

```html
def getNestedAttr(obj,nestedParam):
     next = obj
     for p in nestedParam.split('.'):
         next = getattr(next,p)
     return next


class Issue : pass    
issue = Issue()
issue.status = Issue()
issue.status.name = "Hello"
getattr(issue,'status.name')
'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Issue' object has no attribute 'status.name'
'''
getNestedAttr(issue,'status.name')

#'Hello'
```

simple solution

Answer (score 3):

I made a simple version based on ubntu's answer called [magicattr](https://pypi.org/project/magicattr/) that also works on attrs, lists, and dicts by parsing and walking the ast.

For example, with this class:

```
class Person:
    settings = {
        'autosave': True,
        'style': {
            'height': 30,
            'width': 200
        },
        'themes': ['light', 'dark']
    }
    def __init__(self, name, age, friends):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.friends = friends


bob = Person(name="Bob", age=31, friends=[])
jill = Person(name="Jill", age=29, friends=[bob])
jack = Person(name="Jack", age=28, friends=[bob, jill])
```

You can do this

```
# Nothing new
assert magicattr.get(bob, 'age') == 31

# Lists
assert magicattr.get(jill, 'friends[0].name') == 'Bob'
assert magicattr.get(jack, 'friends[-1].age') == 29

# Dict lookups
assert magicattr.get(jack, 'settings["style"]["width"]') == 200

# Combination of lookups
assert magicattr.get(jack, 'settings["themes"][-2]') == 'light'
assert magicattr.get(jack, 'friends[-1].settings["themes"][1]') == 'dark'

# Setattr
magicattr.set(bob, 'settings["style"]["width"]', 400)
assert magicattr.get(bob, 'settings["style"]["width"]') == 400

# Nested objects
magicattr.set(bob, 'friends', [jack, jill])
assert magicattr.get(jack, 'friends[0].friends[0]') == jack

magicattr.set(jill, 'friends[0].age', 32)
assert bob.age == 32
```

It also won't let you/someone call functions or assign a value since it doesn't use eval or allow Assign/Call nodes.

```
with pytest.raises(ValueError) as e:
    magicattr.get(bob, 'friends = [1,1]')

# Nice try, function calls are not allowed
with pytest.raises(ValueError):
    magicattr.get(bob, 'friends.pop(0)')
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the accepted answer above. It was helpful.
In case anyone wants to extend the use for `hasattr` use the code below:

```py
def rhasattr(obj, attr):
    _nested_attrs = attr.split(".")
    _curr_obj = obj
    for _a in _nested_attrs[:-1]:
        if hasattr(_curr_obj, _a):
            _curr_obj = getattr(_curr_obj, _a)
        else:
            return False
    return hasattr(_curr_obj, _nested_attrs[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so while typing the question I had an idea of how to do this and it seems to work fine. Here is what I came up with:

```
def set_attribute(obj, path_string, new_value):
    parts = path_string.split('.')
    final_attribute_index = len(parts)-1
    current_attribute = obj
    i = 0
    for part in parts:
        new_attr = getattr(current_attribute, part, None)
        if current_attribute is None:
            print 'Error %s not found in %s' % (part, current_attribute)
            break
        if i == final_attribute_index:
            setattr(current_attribute, part, new_value)
        current_attribute = new_attr
        i+=1


def get_attribute(obj, path_string):
    parts = path_string.split('.')
    final_attribute_index = len(parts)-1
    current_attribute = obj
    i = 0
    for part in parts:
        new_attr = getattr(current_attribute, part, None)
        if current_attribute is None:
            print 'Error %s not found in %s' % (part, current_attribute)
            return None
        if i == final_attribute_index:
            return getattr(current_attribute, part)
        current_attribute = new_attr
        i += 1
```

I guess this solves my question, but I am still curious if there is a better way to do this?

I feel like this has to be something pretty common in OOP and python, so I'm surprised gatattr and setattr do not support this natively.

Comment: The name of the last attribute, `final_attribute` can occur more than once. For example, `p.foo.foo` is legal. So the condition `part == final_attribute` may trigger too soon.

Comment: Ahh very good point, I changed to checking the index, which should resolve that issue. Thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

I just love recursive functions

```
def rgetattr(obj,attr):
    _this_func = rgetattr
    sp = attr.split('.',1)
    if len(sp)==1:
        l,r = sp[0],''
    else:
        l,r = sp

    obj = getattr(obj,l)
    if r:
        obj = _this_func(obj,r)
    return obj
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's something similar to ChaimG's answer, but it works with an arbitrary number of cases. However, it only supports get attributes, not setting them.

```
requested_attr = 'pet.name'
parent = Person()

sub_names = requested_attr.split('.')
sub = None

for sub_name in sub_names:

    try:
        sub = parent.__getattribute__(sub_name)
        parent = sub

    except AttributeError:
        raise Exception("The panel doesn't have an attribute that matches your request!")

pets_name = sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is pretty old but below code might help some one.

```
    def getNestedObjectValue(obj={}, attr=""):
    splittedFields = attr.split(".")
    nestedValue = ""
    previousValue = ""
    for field in splittedFields:
        previousValue = nestedValue
        nestedValue = (
            obj.get(field) if previousValue == "" else previousValue.get(field)
        )
    return nestedValue

    print(
    getNestedObjectValue(
        obj={
            "name": "ADASDASD",
            "properties": {"somefield": {"value": "zxczxcxczxcxzc"}},
        },
        attr="properties.somefield.value",
    )
)
```

Output

> PS C:\myprograms\samples> python .\sample.py
>
> zxczxcxczxcxzc