# Apply a method from a list of methods to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, functional-programming, series

this is my first question here so please be patient with me.

My problem is as follows:

Assume we have a pandas Dataframe and we want to apply dynamically some pd.Series methods to a set of columns of this Dataframe. Why the following example doesn't work?

```
testframe=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col1': [1,2] ,'col2': [3,4] })
funcdict={'col1':[pd.Series.astype,str.replace],'col2':[pd.Series.astype,str.replace]}
argdict= {'col1':[['str'],['1','A']],'col2':[['str'],['3','B']]}

for col in testframe.columns:
    for func in funcdict[col]:
            idx=funcdict[col].index(func)
            testframe[col]=testframe[col].func(*argdict[col][idx])
```

Expected outcome would be

```
  col1 col2
0  'A'  'B'
1  '1'  '4'
```

But instead i get

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'func'
```

Remarkably

```
testframe['col1']=testframe['col1'].astype(*argdict['col1'][0])
```

works as expected, so somehow python seems to have a problem with the '.func' syntax despite the fact that

`print(func)`

yields the desired output: 'function NDFrame.astype at 0x00000186954EB840' etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax for calling a method is incorrect. There are 2 ways you can call a method in Python.

**Direct**

As you found, this will work. Note that `astype` isn't referencing some other object, it's the *actual name* of the method belonging to `pd.Series`.

```
testframe['col1'] = testframe['col1'].astype(*argdict['col1'][0])
```

**Functional**

The functional method demonstrates explicitly that `astype` is the name of the method.

```
from operator import methodcaller

testframe['col1'] = methodcaller('astype', *argdict['col1'][0])(testframe[col])
```

Trying `testframe[col].func(...)` will never work as `func` is not the name of a `pd.Series` method.

Comment: This solved my problem by using $func.__name__$ as a first argument for methodcaller. Didn't know about that functionality..thx!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`rgettattr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31174427/190597) to get attributes from the Series, `testframe[col]`:
For example,

```
In [74]: s = pd.Series(['1','2'])

In [75]: rgetattr(s, 'str.replace')('1', 'A')
Out[75]: 
0    A
1    2
dtype: object
```

---

```
import functools
import pandas as pd

def rgetattr(obj, attr, *args):
    def _getattr(obj, attr):
        return getattr(obj, attr, *args)
    return functools.reduce(_getattr, [obj] + attr.split('.'))

testframe = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})

funcdict = {'col1': ['astype', 'str.replace'],
            'col2': ['astype', 'str.replace']}

argdict = {'col1': [['str'], ['1', 'A']], 'col2': [['str'], ['3', 'B']]}

for col in testframe.columns:
    for attr, args in zip(funcdict[col], argdict[col]):
        testframe[col] = rgetattr(testframe[col], attr)(*args)
print(testframe)
```

yields

```
  col1 col2
0    A    B
1    2    4
```

---

[`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) is the function in Python's standard library used for getting a named attribute from an object when the name is given in the form of a string. For example, given

```
In [92]: s = pd.Series(['1','2']); s
Out[92]: 
0    1
1    2
dtype: object
```

we can obtain `s.str` using

```
In [85]: getattr(s, 'str')
Out[85]: <pandas.core.strings.StringMethods at 0x7f334a847208>
In [91]: s.str == getattr(s, 'str')
Out[91]: True
```

To obtain `s.str.replace`, we would need

```
In [88]: getattr(getattr(s, 'str'), 'replace')
Out[88]: <bound method StringMethods.replace of <pandas.core.strings.StringMethods object at 0x7f334a847208>>

In [90]: s.str.replace == getattr(getattr(s, 'str'), 'replace')
Out[90]: True
```

However, if we specify

```
funcdict = {'col1': ['astype', 'str.replace'],
            'col2': ['astype', 'str.replace']}
```

then we need some way of handling cases where we need one call to `getattr`, (e.g. `getattr(testframe[col], 'astype')`) versus those cases where we need multiple calls to `getattr` (e.g. `getattr(getattr(testframe[col], 'str'), 'replace')`.

To unify the two cases into one simple syntax, we can use `rgetattr`, a recursive drop-in replacement for `getattr` which can handle dotted chains of string attribute names such as `'str.replace'`.

The recursion is handled by [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).
The docs give as an example that `reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` calculates `((((1+2)+3)+4)+5)`. Similarly, you can imagine the `+` being replaced by `getattr` so that `rgetattr(s, 'str.replace')` calculates `getattr(getattr(s, 'str'), 'replace')`.

Comment: i'm pretty new to python so i will need some time to digest the details but this looks incredbly elegant (+1)