# Is there a way to set attribute of attribute?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am currently trying to assign an attribute, consider the following example:

```
net = timm.create_model(model_name='regnetx_002', pretrained=False)
net.head.fc = torch.nn.Linear(1111, 2)
```

This seems to work just fine, however, some models have different attributes, like the following

```
net.classifier = torch.nn.Linear(1111,2)
```

Therefore, I am trying to set attribute dynamically. I have already manage to retrieve the names of the attributes, like "head" and "fc", but it seems that you cannot do something like:

```
setattr(net, "head.fc", torch.nn.Linear(1111, 2))
```

as it will create one new attribute "head.fc" instead. I think there is a misunderstanding in my knowledge, as I noticed that when I print the model's last layer, it looks like:

```
  (head): ClassifierHead(
    (global_pool): SelectAdaptivePool2d (pool_type=avg, flatten=True)
    (fc): Linear(in_features=368, out_features=1000, bias=True)
  )
)
```

Is there any way to achieve what I want dynamically.

Comment: How about named tuple? https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setattr(net, "head.fc", torch.nn.Linear(1111, 2))`

will create `head.fc` attribute on net.

I guess you want to create
`setattr(net.head, "fc", torch.nn.Linear(1111, 2))`

or dynamically:

`setattr(getattr(net, "head"), "fc", torch.nn.Linear(1111, 2))`.

If you want an even more **general nested dynamic atrribute**, you'll add to build some helper functions for this, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31174427/3700626).