# Python: Get class parameter when calling class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking to facilitate the following behavior, which is NOT just to get a string representation of the class! The following is a SIMPLIFIED version of my problem:

```
>>> Alphabet.a
'a'
>>> Alphabet.b
'b'
>>> Alphabet.alpha
'α'
>>> Alphabet.a.is_vowel
True
```

I currently have the following setup. The main reason I chose this over any other approach is that the data I am accessing has to, at most, be set on start-up and that this approach is able to make use of my IDEs code completion feature.

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self, c: str, v: bool):
        self.name = c
        self.is_vowel = v

class Alphabet:
    a: Character = Character('a', True)
    b: Character = Character('b', False)
    c: Character = Character('c', False)
```

That already allows me to call `Alphabet.a.name` to get the name, however I'd like to be able to only call `Alphabet.a` to get the name parameter, while still being able to access `Alphabet.a.is_vowel`.

Comment: What do do you want `type(Alphabet.a)` to be?

Comment: You can't make `Alphabet.a` be an actual string, and also have `Alphabet.a.is_vowel` work, because actual strings don't have an attribute `is_vowel`. So at best `Alphabet.a` can be a custom class, and its repr can be customised to look like a string.

Comment: @deceze it is a duplicate, you just had the wrong canonical (the titles are a bit misleading). I'll see what I can do about cleaning it up later.

Comment: @deceze You can, actually. It's not pretty, but it is possible.

Comment: I was hoping for there to be some sort of magic function akin to `def __self__(): return self` that can be overridden to return something else, while still allowing me to access the other parameters.

Comment: @wim I guess you can subclass `str`, yes, but that's really not the solution you would usually want to go for…

Comment: @wim I'd very much like to know how.

Comment: It is also possible without using inheritance / subclass. But it's pretty black magic, and it's not clear why you can't simply add `__str__` and `is_vowel` methods on your `Character` type, that seems like the obvious solution here.

Comment: @wim In this example the main attribute I'm interested in is a string, but if I find an acceptable solution to this problem, I'm going to have different types be the primary type that ought to be returned if only the class instance is called.

Comment: "some sort of magic function akin to def __self__(): return self that can be overridden to return something else" That's what `__str__` and `__repr__` are for. Unless you actually need to get a string as a result, rather than simply controlling how instances are displayed. But in that case, it's considerably more complex: `Alphabet.a.name` **must** mean the same thing as `(Alphabet.a).name`, so if `Alphabet.a` *actually evaluates to a string*, it would have to evaluate to a *subtype of* `str` in order to apply a `name` attribute.

Comment: ... Okay, I tried it and this is *doable*, but I really doubt it's really necessary or desirable. But I won't object to a further re-opening. I'll even write an answer.

Comment: "I'm going to have different types be the primary type that ought to be returned if only the class instance is called" This... isn't comprehensible. I think you misunderstand the meaning of the terminology.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I worded that poorly. In this example, the type of the parameter to be returned when the class instance is called is a string, so `a = Character('a', True)`, `type(a) # type: str`. But I don't intend to have the type of the parameter returned to always be `str`.

Comment: The closest answer to what I want to achieve is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31174295/getattr-and-setattr-on-nested-subobjects-chained-properties

But it doesn#t work with code completion, as the path through the nested parameters is given as a string.

Comment: It's possible to make `Character('a', True)` create a `str` unconditionally, but then a) there's no point to the class, since no instances of it will be created; b) the `str` can't have an `is_vowel` attribute, as it's a built-in type which doesn't allow for setting additional attributes. Working around that requires having a subtype of `str` instead of `str` itself.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel  Again, it is possible without sub-classing, by controlling where "is_vowel" gets looked up. Though, such an approach gets to some pretty dark corners of CPython and I'm still waiting for an answer about what `type(Alphabet.a)` is expected to be.

Comment: @wim As far as I can forsee for now, the type of `Alphabet.a` ought to be the type of `a.name` in this example. And as I said earlier, the `type` of `a.name` won't always be `str`

Comment: @wim I'm afraid I simply can't fathom what you propose. It's not as if you can monkey-patch `str.__getattr__`.

Comment: You cannot simultaneously have `Alphabet.a` provide a `str` and at the same time have `Alphabet.a.some_other_attribute` work since then `Alphabet.a` *cannot be a string* (ok, no sane way)

Comment: And this isn't about strings specifically, `X.y` should be some type, but then that type must have a `.z` attribute if you want to be able to have `X.y.z`. Anything else is fundamentally broken. Or fundamentally requires some black magic (AST re-writing, live call stack modification, dynamic code modification, etc etc). What is fundamentally broken is the *abstraction you've designed*. Thnk of it this way, python sees `X.y.z` not as `X.(y.z)` but as `(X.y).z`