# How to modify parameters that require gradients in meta learning?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, gradient-descent, autograd

I have a neural network that is trained to output learning rates:

```
import torch 
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

class Meta_Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Meta_Model, self).__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1,32)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(32,32)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(32,32)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(32,1)

        self.lky = nn.LeakyReLU(0.1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.lky(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.lky(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.lky(self.fc3(x))
        x = self.fc4(x)
        return x # x should be some learning rate

meta_model = Meta_Model().to(device)
meta_model_opt = optim.Adam(meta_model.parameters(), lr=1e-1)
```

I have some inputs and a function I'm trying to learn:

```
input_tensor = torch.rand(1000,1) # some inputs
label_tensor = 2 * input_tensor # function to learn
```

I'm trying to update **one trainable parameter** to solve this function:

```
meta_model_epochs = 10
w_epochs = 5

for _ in range(meta_model_epochs):
    torch.manual_seed(42) # reset seed for reproducibility
    w1 = torch.rand(1, requires_grad=True) # reset **trainable weight**
    weight_opt = optim.SGD([w1], lr=1e-1) # reset weight optimizer
    meta_loss = 0 # reset meta loss
    for _ in range(w_epochs):
        predicted_tensor = w1 * input_tensor 
        loss = criterion(predicted_tensor, label_tensor)
        meta_loss += loss # add to meta loss
        meta_model_output = meta_model(loss.detach().unsqueeze(0)) # input to the meta model is the loss
        weight_opt.zero_grad()
        loss.backward(retain_graph=True) # get grads

        w1 = w1 - meta_model_output * w1.grad # step --> this is the issue
    
    meta_model_opt.zero_grad()
    meta_loss.backward()
    meta_model_opt.step()
    print('meta_loss', meta_loss.item())
```

So the setting is that the meta model should learn to output the optimal learning rate to update the trainable parameter `w1` based on the current loss.

The issue is that I'm getting `RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [1]] is at version 2; expected version 0 instead. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).`

I also tried replacing the update step with  `w1.data = w1.data - meta_model_output * w1.grad # step`, which resolves the issue, but then the meta model is not updating (i.e., the loss stays the same)

**Update 1:**

Tried @VonC idea of computing the updated value of w1 (using a clone of w1: w1_updated_value) and setting it as the data of w1:

```
w1_clone = w1.clone()
w1_clone = w1_clone - meta_model_output * w1.grad # step
w1.data = w1_clone
```

While this removes the error, it results in the same issue of the meta model is not updating (i.e., the loss stays the same).

**Update 2:**
After lots of readings on buffers and updating leaf tensors I got a solution that updates a whole network:

```
import torch 
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
import functools 
import math 


criterion = nn.MSELoss()
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

class Meta_Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Meta_Model, self).__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1,32)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(32,32)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(32,32)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(32,1)

        self.lky = nn.LeakyReLU(0.1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.lky(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.lky(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.lky(self.fc3(x))
        x = self.fc4(x)
        return x # x should be some learning rate

meta_model = Meta_Model().to(device)
meta_model_opt = optim.Adam(meta_model.parameters(), lr=1e-1)
input_tensor = torch.rand(1000,1) # some inputs
label_tensor = 2 * input_tensor # function to learn
meta_model_epochs = 10
w_epochs = 5

############## the new solution
def rsetattr(obj, attr, val):
    pre, _, post = attr.rpartition('.')
    return setattr(rgetattr(obj, pre) if pre else obj, post, val)

# using wonder's beautiful simplification: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31174295/getattr-and-setattr-on-nested-objects/31174427?noredirect=1#comment86638618_31174427

def rgetattr(obj, attr, *args):
    def _getattr(obj, attr):
        return getattr(obj, attr, *args)
    return functools.reduce(_getattr, [obj] + attr.split('.'))

class MetaLinear(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features, out_features, bias=True):
        super().__init__()
        # Initialize weights and biases to zero
        # The line below is nearly identical to "self.weight = ...", but we get all of the added PyTorch features.
        self.register_buffer('weight', torch.zeros(out_features, in_features, requires_grad=True))
        if bias:
            self.register_buffer('bias', torch.zeros(out_features, requires_grad=True))
        else:
            self.bias = None
        
        # Fancy initialization from https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-are-layer-weights-and-biases-initialized-by-default/13073
        stdv = 2. / math.sqrt(self.weight.size(1))
        self.weight.data.uniform_(-stdv, stdv)
        if self.bias is not None:
            self.bias.data.uniform_(-stdv, stdv)
            
    def forward(self, x):
        return F.linear(x, self.weight, self.bias)    

class Weights_network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Weights_network, self).__init__()

        self.fc1 = MetaLinear(1,8, bias=True)
        self.fc2 = MetaLinear(8,8, bias=True)
        self.fc3 = MetaLinear(8,8, bias=True)
        self.fc4 = MetaLinear(8,1, bias=True)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc4(x))
        return x

class CustomeOptimizer():
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.named_buffers = model.named_buffers()
        self.model = model

    def zero_grad(self):
        for name, param in self.named_buffers:
            if param.grad:
                param.grad.zero_()

    def step(self, meta_output_lr): 
        for name, param in self.model.named_buffers():
            clipping_value = 1e-2
            clipped_gradient = torch.clip(param.grad.detach().clone(), min = -clipping_value, max = clipping_value)
            new_param = (param.clone() - meta_output_lr.to(device) * clipped_gradient)            
            new_param.retain_grad()
            rsetattr(self.model, name, new_param)        
##############

for _ in range(meta_model_epochs): # meta training loop
    meta_loss = 0 # meta loss
    torch.manual_seed(42)
    w1 = Weights_network().to(device) # reset network
    # maintain grad
    for name, param in w1.named_buffers():
        param.retain_grad()     
    weight_opt = CustomeOptimizer(w1) # reset optimizer
    for _ in range(w_epochs): # weights training loop
        predicted_tensor = w1(input_tensor)
        loss = criterion(predicted_tensor, label_tensor)
        meta_loss += loss
        meta_model_output = meta_model(loss.detach().unsqueeze(0)).to(device)
        weight_opt.zero_grad()
        loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
        weight_opt.step(meta_model_output)

    meta_model_opt.zero_grad()
    meta_loss.backward()
    meta_model_opt.step()
    print('meta_loss', meta_loss.item())
>>> 
meta_loss 0.9203591346740723
meta_loss 0.4630056917667389
meta_loss 5.195590972900391
meta_loss 0.44623494148254395
meta_loss 0.45180386304855347
meta_loss 0.5693209767341614
meta_loss 0.43741166591644287
meta_loss 0.5331400632858276
meta_loss 0.5698808431625366
meta_loss 0.4637502133846283
```

Though, 1) I'm not sure why this works as the update step seems similar to what I tried. 2) Since I don't understand why this works I can't figure out how to use this on my initial setup where I have a simple parameter `w1` that is not a whole network

**Update 3:** Tried @VonC suggestion on wrapping my tensor of weights as a buffer:

```
import torch 
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import functools 

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

class Meta_Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Meta_Model, self).__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1,32)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(32,32)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(32,32)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(32,1)

        self.lky = nn.LeakyReLU(0.1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.lky(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.lky(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.lky(self.fc3(x))
        x = self.fc4(x)
        return x # x should be some learning rate

class Weights(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Weights, self).__init__()
        self.register_buffer('w1', torch.rand(1, requires_grad=True))

meta_model = Meta_Model().to(device)
meta_model_opt = optim.Adam(meta_model.parameters(), lr=1e-1)
input_tensor = torch.rand(1000,1) # some inputs
label_tensor = 2 * input_tensor # function to learn
meta_model_epochs = 10
w_epochs = 5

for _ in range(meta_model_epochs):
    torch.manual_seed(42)
    w1 = Weights().w1
    weight_opt = optim.SGD([w1], lr=0)  # Set learning rate to zero
    meta_loss = 0
    for _ in range(w_epochs):
        predicted_tensor = w1 * input_tensor
        loss = criterion(predicted_tensor, label_tensor)
        meta_loss += loss
        meta_model_output = meta_model(loss.detach().unsqueeze(0))
        weight_opt.zero_grad()
        loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
        # Compute updated value of w1
        w1_updated = w1.clone() - meta_model_output * w1.grad
        w1_updated.retain_grad()
        # Use w1_updated as input to the next iteration
        w1 = w1_updated

    meta_model_opt.zero_grad()
    meta_loss.backward()
    meta_model_opt.step()
    print('meta_loss', meta_loss.item())
```

But I'm still getting the inplace operation runtime error.

Comment: Could you try and use the `.detach()` method to create a copy of the tensor that is not part of the computation graph? And instead of modifying w1 directly, create a new tensor that represents the updated value of w1. That would avoid the in-place modification issue.

Comment: @VonC Thanks for the help on this! Not sure I follow. I can create `new_w1` and update it's value, but I will still need to update `w1`. Won't that be the same as what I tried with `w1.data = w1.data - meta_model_output * w1.grad`?

Comment: Right... maybe manually compute the updated value of w1 (using a clone of w1: w1_updated_value) and set it as the data of w1.

Comment: @VonC If I understood correctly this didn't quite work -- see my update. Correct me if I misunderstood something

Comment: OK. From what I can see, I tried to formulate an answer below.

Comment: I have deleted my answer to remove the noise. I hope you will find an answer.

Comment: @VonC Thanks a lot for the help! I got a solution that seems to be working, but on a whole network. Not sure if you're still interested but I updated my question

Comment: Nice, well done: you are updating the parameters in a way that is tracked by the autograd system: your updates are not in-place modifications on `nn.Parameter` objects, but rather changes to buffers that are part of the model's state, which does preserve the computational graph. Applying this method to a single parameter (`w1`) would require thinking of `w1` as a buffer instead of a regular parameter. However, this might be overkill for a single parameter. The complexity of this solution is more justified when dealing with multiple parameters or entire layers.

Comment: @VonC Thanks! Took a while to figure this out. Any idea how to adjust this to a tensor of weights like in my original question? e.g., `w1`? Or even a more complex tensor of weights, e.g., `torch.rand(30,30)` -- again, that is not a part of a network? Seems like the buffers must be inside of a network if I understand correctly `self.register_buffer`. I'm using the one parameter as a way to evaluate if this meta learning setup works in the first place. My actual setting is slightly more complex

Comment: Since `register_buffer` is tied to `nn.Module`, you can create a simple wrapper module that holds your tensor as a buffer. You can use this wrapper to encapsulate your tensor (e.g., `w1` or a `torch.rand(30, 30)` tensor)

Comment: @VonC I tried it, but seems like I'm still getting the inplace operation error -- see update 3. Is that what you had in mind? I'm probably missing something

Comment: I see that `w1` is directly referenced from the `Weights` class instance and updated in each iteration. This direct update of `w1` should break the computational graph, as the tensor w1 is a buffer and doesn't inherently support autograd. I cannot test the Wrapper Module approach (which involves encapsulating the tensor within an `nn.Module`), so I will refrain to post it.

Comment: @VonC I'm slightly confused. How else would you update it? Or capture it's gradient? I don't really understand how this is different than `Update 2` since the weights are also buffers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256033/discussion-between-vonc-and-penguin).